# Taking integer value from URL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, url, isset

I have this dummy URL : http://blahblah.co.uk/node/57?url=/Installer/Manufacturer/17/Schuco

I need the number "17" from this URL in order to query the database.

I have looked into using "isset()" but am not sure it is the right approach.

Can someone show me how to strip this URL down?

Thanks

This is what I have so far:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo $url;
```

Comment: Already have. sorry, only just updated the code @Daan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `explode()` to strip the `$url` and get the `17`

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$parts = Explode('/', $url);
$part = $parts[7]; //17
```

You can change the 7 to get the right part of the url.

edit (after comment):

```
print_r($parts);
```

will give you

```
Array ( [0] => http: 
        [1] => 
        [2] => blahblah.co.uk 
        [3] => node 
        [4] => 57?url= 
        [5] => Installer 
        [6] => Manufacturer 
        [7] => 17 
        [8] => Schuco 
)
```

So you can see that number 7 gives you `17` 
    `echo $parts[7]; // 17`

Comment: So why is the array value 4? @C Travel

Comment: Good question, after testing i came to the conclusion it was number 7, when you are exploding the full url

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense. Thanks @C Travel

Comment: Updates my answers with the output of `print_r($parts);`

Comment: So basically "Explode" just splits strings that are separated by common things like "/" in to array items? @C Travel

Answer (score 1):

Better if you will use PHP function `parse_url` to parse the URL.

Check below code :

```
$url = 'http://blahblah.co.uk/node/57?url=/Installer/Manufacturer/17/Schuco';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$explodeUrl = explode('/', $parsedUrl['query']);

echo $explodeUrl[3]; // 17
```

Now, you will get all the details of the URL you passed.

Comment: The number will change though depending on the product they choose. So setting the URL as a variable may not be the best approach. @prava

Comment: @sMilbz, can you please give 1-2 examples of such, so that I can come up with a definite solution :)

Comment: Well there are 57 products in total, so every time a product is selected, the "17" will correlate to the product ID. The rest of the url will stay the same @prava

Comment: @sMilbz, what I got from your comment, the link will be same everytime, only the ID will change, like - 
http://blahblah.co.uk/node/57?url=/Installer/Manufacturer/17/Schuco OR http://blahblah.co.uk/node/57?url=/Installer/Manufacturer/32/Schuco OR http://blahblah.co.uk/node/57?url=/Installer/Manufacturer/212/Schuco ... 

If the URL will come like above, then no worries :) the above code will work for all :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `preg_match()`

```
$str = 'http://blahblah.co.uk/node/57?url=/Installer/Manufacturer/17/Schuco';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $str, $matches);
print($matches[0][1]); // 17
```